# Where to find Orders details page frontend magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, order-details

I want to change the design of Orders details page in magneto 2 frontend, but I don't know which page to edit. Is it in module-sales?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to modify the orders list page in customers account - here is the corresponding layout:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_history.xml
```

You can duplicate it in custom theme (active on your store) and modify as you want.

Here is the layout for the order view page (customer account):

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_view.xml
```